# What is the range of typeset -i variable

Tags: shell

Below is my script

```
#!/bin/sh

typeset resl=$(($1+$2))
echo $resl
```

when i am passing two value **173591451** and **2000252844** to shell script, it is returning negative value.

**./addvalue.sh 173591451 2000252844**

output ---> **-2121123001**

Please let me know how we can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Dropping into a friendly programming calculator application to look at your values in hex I see you are into 32-bits of precision. Once you hit 32-bits (8'th digit >= 8) you have exceeded the size of integer your shell was compiled with and entered the land of negative numbers (but that's another post).

```
   0x81923B47 = 0xA58CB9B + 0x77396FAC
```

Two workarounds, without having to worry about getting a 64-bit shell, follow.

**1. awk**

The success of this depends on how your awk as compiled and which awk you are using.

```
awk 'END {print 173591451 + 2000252844}' </dev/null
```

Also do all your relational testing in awk.

**2. dc**

The "dc" program (desk calculator) uses arbitrary precision so you never need to worry about integer bit-size again. To put it into a variable:

```
   $ sum="$( echo 173591451 2000252844 + p | dc )"; echo $sum
2173844295
```

And avoid `typeset -i` with **dc** as the shell needs to see strings. Properly checking relationships (if `$a < $b`) gets a little tricky, but can be done (`$a -lt $b` is wrong).

Comment: Oh, yes... the valid range of integer variables.  -(1<<(n-1)) through  (1<<(n-1))-1 where n is the bits in an "int" integer (these days 32 or 64). The << indicates left shift, so 1<<4 is 16. For 1<< this is the same as 2**4.